# An event for all view nested in a screen android

Tags: android, events, view, touch

I have a view with many child views nested in it (example: LinearLayout, Edittext, Imageview, Button...). After fill the text in Edittext, I want to send one event for all view in the screen (any position is touched/clicked) to the new screen. I also ref in many forum but can not find out my problem. Please help me this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that you can use `getChildCount` and `getChildAt` functions of ViewGroup. And for all childs you can call this event.